# Is it possible to remove the letter prefix ("a. ", "b. ", etc.) from the possible answers in mulitple choice tests?

Tags: r-exams

When producing multiple choice questions, `exams` prefixes the possible answers with lower case letters. Is it possible to change this behaviour when using `exams2qti21` so that the answers are displayed without this prefix?

e.g. to go from

```
a. 12
b. 35
c. 15
d. 25
```

to simply,

```
12
35
15
25
```

I would like to do this because our content management system, "itsLearning" can randomise the possible answers (per student) and the inclusion of the letter prefixes messes this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `enumerate` argument to `FALSE` for the `mchoice` and/or `schoice` questions. By default, the setting of `mchoice` is also propagated to `schoice`. So this should do what you want:

```
exams2qti21(..., mchoice = list(enumerate = FALSE))
```

As an additional comment:

- Letting the learning management system do the randomization is more efficient if the exercises and choice lists are otherwise static. Then you just need to upload one exercise and re-use it because the learning management system does the shuffling.
- Letting the `exams2xyz()` interface from R/exams do the shuffling, on the other hand, gives you far more options than most learning management systems support. In particular you can generate the choice lists fully dynamically (as in [deriv2](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/deriv2/) or [tstat2](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/tstat2/)) or you can do subsampling from a large static list (as in [capitals](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/capitals/)). In both cases I would switch off the shuffling in the learning management system.